# Reverse calculation of an existing formula

Tags: math, excel-formula

I have this formula

```
D5 = 10000
D4 = 9726.76

=SUM((D5 - D4) * ((1500 *1) / D4))
```

The results will be: `42.13736126`

And I'm looking for way to provide the result and get the D5 (10000);

I hope this is understandable enough :)

Comment: Your result is actually -40.986

Comment: I test it again I still get 42.13736126 :)

Comment: That is a mathematical approach and the `SUM` doesn't do anything as it gets only one value. `z=(x - y) * ((1500*1)/x)` would be `y=x-z/((1500*1)/x)`... so with the result at D6 `=D4 - D6/((1500*1)/D4)` (still you could skip the `*1`)

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks, but I get different result, with `=D4 - D6/((1500*1)/D4)` I got: `9453.52`, and about the *1 in my case sometimes it's different number

Comment: it's should be D4 + D6 not minus, but thanks! :)

Comment: True... flipped the first part `(x - y)` which should be `(y - x)`... sorry... but as you showed effort in solving your own problem I'll throw a +1 ;)

Comment: Isn't that simple algebra?

Comment: The `SUM()` function with one argument just returns that argument (I hope). So the formula should be _identical_ to `=(D5 - D4) * ((1500 *1) / D4)`. From this point on it is simple algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what cell the 42.137 is in, but the formula is:

```
(Result*D4)/(1*1500)+D4
```